# Edit Profile gives me algorithm, iterations and hash in Django

Tags: python, django, passwords

When I go to my "edit profile" page this is what it looks like:

[image]

So it shows me the algorithm, iterations and hash. And if I want to remove it form my forms.py (remove password):

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    template_name='/something/else'

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            **'password'**
        )
```

It shows me this:

[image]

Feel free to share your ideas.

Comment: What were you looking to do here? I am not sure it is/was clear what you were asking.

Comment: @halfer thanks for asking. I already solved the problem. I need help in writting in the ldap, after that my website is done. If you know anything don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Great! I assume you have asked a new question about the LDAP. Since this question is solved, would you provide an answer below? It may help a future visitor.

Comment: yes off course. I am just really frustrated because I can't write in my LDAP. I can loggin as a LDAP user because my Backend works. But I don' have the knowledge to write in it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code form forms.py to an editable code in edit_profile.html (that takes the entries form forms.py):

edit_profile.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="first_name">Vorname </label>
    <input style="margin-bottom: 1em;" id="first_name" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="25" name="first_name" value="{{ user.first_name }}"><br>
    <label for="last_name">Nachname </label>
    <input style=" margin-bottom: 1em;" id="last_name" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="25" name="last_name" value="{{ user.last_name }}"><br>
    <label for="email">E-Mail </label>
    <input style="margin-bottom: 1em;" id="email" class="form-control" type="email" maxlength="50" required=True unique=True name="email" value="{{ user.email }}"><br>

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit">Bestätigen</button>
    <a style="margin-left: 1em;" href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile' %}" id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-default">Zurück</button></a>

    {% if form.errors %}
      <p style="margin-left: 5em;" class=" label label-danger">
          Das ist keine gültige E-Mail-Adresse. Bitte versuche Sie es erneut.
      </p>
    {% endif %}

</form>
```